# salesforce.com - Role based hierarchy in report access

Tags: salesforce

I want to create a scenario where in , people have access to reports based on their role and level in the hierarchy.For example a sales representative who is reporting to a sales director should not have access to the reports that the sales director has but the sales director has access to all the reports that the sales rep has access to and in addition has access to few other reports which are not relevant to the sales representative. Could you please help me with the solution.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Report security is set at the reports folder level. Create a folder for director, place his reports in that folder and set folder accessibility to his role (or public group). For sales people create a different folder and set its security to directors role + subordinates (or both their public groups).